# Unable to find connector in eagle library

Tags: pcb, connector, eaglecad

I am designing a PCB in `Cadsoft Eagle`. I need to connect this type of connector:

[image: Connector Drawing]
<sup>[Image Source](http://my.solidworks.com/search/tile/1?q=cvilux)</sup>

But these connectors are not available in eagle libraries. 
Does anyone have any idea about how to use these connectors in designing PCB.

Comment: Quick and dirty just use a regular pin header with same pitch and amount of pins

Comment: Make the part yourself.  You would have been done by now if you'd sat down and did it instead of looking for a freebie out there.

Comment: They are called Molex-KK connectors, and you can find them if you look through the ```con-molex``` library. The equivalent would be ```22-23-2101``` from that lib.

Comment: As well as the `con-molex` library, it is in one of [SparkFun's Public Eagle PCB Footprints libraries](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries)

Comment: Make your own library components. Simple as that.

Comment: you can get that part from con-amp library or con-molex library

Comment: There's no way in this day and age (and even 5 years ago) that the standard libraries don't have common parts like this. Making your own is only useful if you are making custom parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have three options.

1. See if they exist in an Eagle library you have - either the exact part of one with equivalent footprint
2. Google search "eagle library + part" and see if anyone has made one already.
3. Make your own based on the datasheets drawings and recommended land patterns (this is probably the most reliable way to ensure you get exactly what you need).

In all cases, make sure to compare the part you find in a library with the datasheet. *Don't* assume that whoever designed the part bothered to check, or made it correctly.

---

In your particular case, the connectors appear equivalent to the standard Molex-KK type connectors. Eagle comes with a library called `con-molex` which contains parts from that series - specifically `22-23-2101` is a 10-pin 0.1" pitch KK connector. But as I said above, if you are going to use this, *make sure to verify with the datasheet that it is the correct footprint*.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question rather simple. Use the tools of the CAD package to design your own footprint and add it to your library. Simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is. Search at this website for 3D models: [4 pin Molex connector](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WTB_2_54_MALE_LOCKING_HEADER_6190XX11121?sq=Molex%204%20Pin)

Altough, Tom's answer is the safest bet.

[image]